# How to upload c# code with Visual Studio to Arduino Mega

Tags: c#, arduino, visual-studio-2013, sonarqube, robotics

So I've decided to try my hand with coding and Arduino's.  My project is a autonomous robot that will navigate itself using a HC-SR04 sonar module which will be using an Arduino Mega 2560 as the controller. I found a forum where a guy was working on the same idea that I had.  I was able to get all of his code from him though it is in c#. And I know anything at all about c#.

Ive done some research and it seems that you can upload code in this case c# to the arduino via visual studio 2013, though I cant seem to figure it out. How can I take the code that I have which is complied in c# and upload it to the arduino mega 2560?

Now this c# code was written for a netduino 2 but I would like to be able to make it work on a arduino mega because that is my current hardware setup.

I have attached some pictures below of the folder structure where the c# code resides, could someone also tell me which files I should be using to upload to the arduino, is there a project file that house everything or do I have to compile this somehow first then upload it to the arduino?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

[Project Home with Source Files](http://fritzing.org/projects/netduino-autonomous-vehicle-with-sonar)

[image: Level 1 of the Source folder]

[image: Level 2 of the Source folder]

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you can put C# code into an Arduino- more likely you can put standard C code into it via some compiler and then communicate with that running code via serial using a C# app running on the PC.

Comment: You might possibly be right a lot of the research that I've done does correlate a lot to that. Though some people said that it was possible to upload to the arduino with c# code.  I just don't know enough about it to figure out if it is possible and even how.

Comment: Actually, you can run C# code on the Netduino, which runs .Net Micro framework. But on the Mega 2560, by default you are bound to native (C/C++) code.

Comment: This is true I was contemplating just buying a netdunio but I think I might just stick with the mega for now and either find some c/c++ code or write my own. But thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know Arduino is programmed in C. What you can do is to install an add-on in Visual studio that allows you to use VS as IDE for Arduino making the life easier if you are writing your program in c# to interface with Arduino. Moreover the add-on allows you to test with the debug features of VS. The add-on is called [visualmicro](http://www.visualmicro.com).

Comment: I do have the plugin installed and I can see my board via the USB serial interface but is it possible for an arduino mega to use c# code? Or is the c# code used to just talk per say with the arduino?

Comment: Forget entirely about C# for the moment and learn how to get a C program running on the Arduino, doing what you want, and communicating via serial port (i.e. printing stuff out in a serial terminal and possibly letting you send commands back to it). Then you can start looking into how you replace the serial terminal with a C# app. Try and do too much from square 1 and you'll just repeatedly bash your head against a brick wall and get nowhere.

Comment: Haha I like it, you guys are right though i might have just bitten off to much to chew, Thank you for all your help!